# How to group query with count requests

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
IIN
LastName
FirstName
MiddleName
```

I need to group values by IIN row, because it contains duplicates.

I need table like this but without duplicates and I can't edit a table

[image]

I use Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here.. show some sample data and desired results. Maybe also show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() function with partition by in IIN column and filter out the duplicates.

```sql
SELECT iin 
,LastName
,FirstName
,MiddleName
from
(SELECT IIN
,LastName
,FirstName
,MiddleName
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by IIN ORDER BY IIN) as rnk
FROM Table ) as t
WHERE rnk =1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you are after, but you can count distinct values in this way:

```sql
select count(*) as [RowCount], count(distinct t.IIN) as [UniqueIINCount]
from dbo.Mytable t;
```